# How do I get hot Reload to work with flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have tried just about everything. Uninstalled the flutter plug in, made sure my path was right. Ran flutter doctor and everything is fine. Ran flutter clean up.

Even tried switching to windows beta.

Can't do a hot Reload when I run in windows app but I can do it when I run it for chrome.

Using Android Studio bumblebee which I have also reinstalled.

Any other advice?

Added my flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.11.0-0.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1526], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.11.0-0.1.pre at C:\Users\pluca\Documents\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b101bfe32f (7 days ago), 2022-02-16 07:36:54 -0800
    • Engine revision e355993572
    • Dart version 2.17.0 (build 2.17.0-69.2.beta)
    • DevTools version 2.10.0-dev.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\pluca\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.0)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.1.32210.238
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1526]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.102
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 98.0.1108.56

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Does it work when you use `flutte run` from the command line and press `r`?

Comment: @jamesdlin, nothing happens.  Also, if I change the primary swatch color, even stopping the app and rerunning it doesn't change the color b

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I was running Visual Studio 2022. I uninstalled it an installed Visual Studio 2019.

Now it works!!!

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you now, but this doesn't make any sense since you said that running `flutter run` directly from the command-line also didn't work, and that has no dependence on your IDE.

Comment: I don't get it either.